# azure-sdk-for-net:Compiling source code

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net

Cloned azure-sdk-for-net from [this github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) and can't compile source in VS 2013 Update 3. I first tried to restore NuGet packages via the "Restore" button in the IDE, but got this message: "An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unbale to find veriosn '1.0.5400.37276-prerelease' of package 'Hyak.Generator'.

I also tried the PM console withe the following command, Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries -IncludePrerelease. This command and other instructions can be found [here.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) That command resulted in the following log:

> Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not
>   responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party
>   packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by
>   additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine
>   any dependencies.
>
> Package Manager Console Host Version 2.8.50313.46
>
> Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.
>
> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries
>   -IncludePrerelease Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common (≥ 1.3.0 && < 2.0)'. Attempting to
>   resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies (≥
>   1.1.0)'. Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management (≥ 2.0.0)'. Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute (≥ 5.0.0)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.MediaServices (≥ 2.0.0)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring (≥ 1.0.0)'. Attempting
>   to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Network (≥
>   3.0.0)'. Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler (≥ 3.0.0)'. Attempting to
>   resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql (≥ 3.0.0)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage (≥ 3.0.0)'. Attempting to
>   resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites (≥
>   3.0.0)'. Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies 1.1.0'. Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies 1.1.0'. Installing
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common 1.3.0'. You are downloading
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common from Microsoft, the license agreement to
>   which is available at http://aka.ms/windowsazureapache2. Check the
>   package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own
>   license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies
>   constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not
>   accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components
>   from your device. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common 1.3.0'. Installing
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management 2.0.0'. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management 2.0.0'. Installing
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute 5.0.0'. Successfully
>   installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute 5.0.0'.
>   Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.MediaServices 2.0.0'.
>   Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.MediaServices 2.0.0'. Installing
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring 1.0.0'. Successfully
>   installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring 1.0.0'.
>   Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Network 3.0.0'.
>   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Network
>   3.0.0'. Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler 3.0.0'. Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler 3.0.0'. Installing
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql 3.0.0'. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql 3.0.0'. Installing
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage 3.0.0'. Successfully
>   installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage 3.0.0'.
>   Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites 3.0.0'.
>   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites
>   3.0.0'. Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries 2.0.0'. Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries 2.0.0'. Adding
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies 1.1.0' to
>   WebSiteManagement. Successfully added
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies 1.1.0' to
>   WebSiteManagement. Adding 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common 1.3.0' to
>   WebSiteManagement. Uninstalling 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common 1.3.0'.
>   Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common 1.3.0'.
>   Install failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : Could not install
>   package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common 1.3.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-net403+win+wpa81', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly  references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries -IncludePrerelease
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
>   PM>

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still see this error, pull the latest version from the repo.